# sitecore upload order media first or content first

Tags: sitecore

While installing content and media(separate package) in Sitecore package installer, is there an order we need to keep in mind?

I think it makes sense to upload Media first and then the content. Else (content first) content will have broken links to media. So is it correct that there is an order and Media should be first (in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter. The link will be active when the package containing the image is installed later.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem more logical to install the media first, but it is not a hard requirement. If you install the content first, you will indeed have broken references but those will be fixed when installing the media.

If you would install the content first, just don't publish until you have your media installed as well (otherwise the broken reference becomes a broken link indeed).

So not a real requirement, but to be honest, I would also install media first... (just makes more sense)